# warning: left shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

i got this problem?
warning: left shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
*sensor_time = (uint32_t)((msb  << 16) | (xlsb << 8) | lsb);

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It depends on bitshifted type. You probably need:  `(((uint32_t)msb << 16) | ((uint32_t)xlsb << 8) | lsb);` as msb and xlsb are probably uint8_t

Answer (score 0):

long may be a 32-bit or 64-bit type depending on your system, 1 is still an int. You need to make 1 a long int using the L suffix as shown below:

try code below

```
unsigned long x = 1UL << 32;
```

or

```
unsigned long long x = 1ULL << 32
```